# Xamarin PCLStorage package: What is the root folder this PCLStorage reference to

Tags: android, xamarin, cross-platform, storage, printer-control-language

I saw this package on Xamarin page. To access the file system I can use PCLStorage.FileStream.Current.localStorage to get the current root storage of the device but which folder it referring to on device: Is it the application private folder or somewhere else?

Can we access other folders e.g. On android, there DOCUMENT, DOWNLOAD folders?

Answer (score 2):

`PCLStorage` [source](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage/blob/d1b905429d0686ed8dfdf03c26fe83ea3c5857ce/src/PCLStorage.FileSystem.Desktop/DesktopFileSystem.cs#L23) for `LocalStorage`:

```
#if ANDROID
var localAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
#elif IOS
var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

In `Android` this maps to the root of app's private storage, i.e.:

```
/data/data/{ApplicationID}/files
```

In iOS, this is mapped to the app's private Documents folder:

```
/data/data/{Package}/Documents
```

If your app requirements differ, you would need to mod the source of that project or provide your own platform code via a `Xamarin.Forms` dependency service.